# New at MySQL, I get the opposite result I want

Tags: mysql, sql

Question: Get part names for parts that are not supplied for job J3. (Use only sub query)

Table info:

Supplier {s_num, s_name, status, city}

Spj {s_num, p_num, j_num, qty}

This is what I have:

```
SELECT pname, color
FROM Part
WHERE p_num = ANY (SELECT p_num
                    FROM Spj
                    WHERE j_num = 'j3');
```

Obviously here I am getting the parts that were supplied FOR job j3.

When I flip it to this:

```
SELECT pname, color
FROM Part
WHERE p_num = ANY (SELECT p_num
                    FROM Spj
                    WHERE j_num <> 'j3');
```

My result lists out every part from the parts table, BECAUSE the other jobs sold at least 1 of each part.

I believe the question wants to exclude any part that was sold in job j3 from the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this formulation:

```
SELECT pname, color
FROM Part
WHERE p_num NOT IN (SELECT p_num
                    FROM Spj
                    WHERE j_num = 'j3'
                   );
```

I find `IN` and `NOT IN` easier to understand than `ANY`, `SOME`, and `ALL`.